# Is it in line with Islam to call themselves "Army of Jesus" and carry icons of Jesus Christ?

Tags: prophet-isa, image

In [this video](https://youtu.be/wEEBfz_EFYQ?t=1046) Apti Alautdiniv, the Akhmat batallion commander from Chechnya calls his unit "army of Jesus" and the soldiers are seen to carry flags with icon of Jesus Christ.

I wonder whether this behavior is in line with Islam? Are there any historical precedents of similar behavior of Muslims?

Comment: I don't see a problem with calling themselves 'army of Jesus', as Jesus  عليه السلام is a Messenger in Islam and there are prophecies of his second coming where he would lead an army against the Dajjal (anti-christ). As for the flags, images are not permitted in Islam, especially when they are images depicting prophets see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38980/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's very uncommon behavior in the history of Islam. As UmH comment stated, there's nothing wrong with saying "Army of Jesus", since Muslims believe in his prophecy and that his crucifixion story has been distorted, however, such icons are prohibited https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38982/56455.

Comment: From the same video they also talk about "Three-united Rus", which in Russian sounds like "trinitarian Rus" (God is commonly called "three-united" in Orthodox Christianity). I am not sure if it is indicative of anything though.