# Is promoting anime permissible in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram

Me and my friend have a youtube channel, we promote anime, some are ecchi, and some contain music. Is it haram that we promote this anime?

And if i quit and my partner doesn't delete the video's I created, do I still get bad deeds for it?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This could be helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26452/is-watching-cartoons-anime-for-entertainment-haram?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Allah has forbidden us to commit sin and do haraam things directly, and He has also forbidden us to help others in doing so. Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> “Say (O Muhammad): (But) the things that my Lord has indeed forbidden
>   are Al‑Fawaahish (great evil sins and every kind of unlawful sexual
>   intercourse) whether committed openly or secretly, sins (of all
>   kinds), unrighteous oppression, joining partners (in worship) with
>   Allaah for which He has given no authority, and saying things about
>   Allaah of which you have no knowledge”

[al-‘Araaf 7:33]

> “Help you one another in Al‑Birr and At‑Taqwa (virtue, righteousness
>   and piety); but do not help one another in sin and transgression. And
>   fear Allaah. Verily, Allaah is Severe in punishment”

[al-Maa'idah 5:2]

Since drawing Anime comprises forbidden/Haram actions, promoting it is equally Haram. Likewise continued display of Anime on a YouTube page would increase your sins so you must repent and try your best to remove the videos you created. If your friend does not cooperate then leave the matter to Allah and make a sincere repentance.

Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

There are different views on the matter, but in general, you are better off promoting what goes against the teachings of Islam, and you should seek forgiveness from Allah for what happened in the past. However, if it is normal, then it should be okay, and Allah knows best. ([Arabic source](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/Fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=3127))

For this, you need to be really sincere when you decide what you are going to promote and what not, and it might be delicate, and you should be responsible of what you are promoting. I remember once I was in a similar position, and decided not to promote an anime as its main theme was about gods and so on, and that it was directed to children. So basically it is boring for adults, and will be mostly watched by early teenagers, so I talked about it to my peers, but not to youngsters.

If you really want to do it, then make sure it is proper, and there is no need to say that eechi is improper. So you either take the responsibility, or let it off.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Thanks, I edited the answer.