# Is drawing cartoon portraits of humans in Photoshop prohibited In Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, image, cartoon

Is it lawful in Islam to draw cartoon portraits of humans in Photoshop?

[image: example drawing]

This is made using a computer.  I am learning to make cartoon portraits of people, as many people love their portraits and ask me to make one of their picture. I have uploaded one picture here for example, so please help me and make it clear with hadith references.

Comment: Related questions: [Is downloading cartoon images Haram?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27471); 
[Is watching cartoons/anime for entertainment Haram?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26452); 
[Is promoting anime permissible in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30683)

Answer (score -1):

no this should not be haram. Only the direct mimications of the depictions of the prophet (saw) and allah (swa) would be forbidden. As long as you're not creating images of any holy figures, this is allowed.

Answer (score -2):

Sketches are haram of every living thing i.e human and animals, The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The most severely punished of the people on the Day of Resurrection will be the image-makers.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (5950) and Muslim (2109).

Comment: Why would it be haram for a Muslim to draw a living thing? Because a Muslim don’t worship it only God Almighty and that’s it, so why would it be?