# Is downloading picture from google and uploading it to youtube haram?

Tags: halal-haram, image, internet

So stealing money is a huge sin. If you made a debt and didnt pay it, you will pay it in the hereafter. 
So mu question is, what if i make some top 10 anime stuff and wanted to put pictures in my video and i get some anime pictures in the google without permission (from the original creator) and uploaded the vid. Then i would earn money from it through google adsense. So does this count as stealing?

And are making youtub reactions to vid and i would also gain money also haram?

Pls awnser and may Allah bless you

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Islam respects copyright; see [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=82812).  However, what precisely this means is not straightforward, and depends on the circumstances:

- The US, for instance, has a [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) policy on using copyrighted material.
- Both Google and YouTube will have their own restrictions of fair use.
- Each site you source images from will have their own restrictions.
- Your country may have its own regulations.

Wikipedia, for instance, has a [low resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Non-free_content/Definition_of_%22low_resolution%22) policy.  This might be relevant if you're taking high-resolution images and converting them to lower-resolution images on YouTube.  It's also better to give attribution (e.g., a link to where the image came from).

---

Other points:

- There's some concerns about whether anime is permissible: [Is watching cartoons/anime for entertainment Haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26452/17163)
- Scholars who consider piracy as a form of "theft" are rare; see [Is piracy a form of theft for the purposes of fiqh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35628/17163)